# jQuery Plugin Function Call With .On

Tags: jquery, dynamic

If I have a jQuery plugin as follows:

```
(function($)
{
    $.fn.somefunction = function(text, options){
        ...function code goes here
    };

    $('.selector_name').somefunction();
})(jQuery);
```

How do I cause it to be bound with the .on function so that it will run for dynamically loaded elements.

I have tried:

```
(function($)
{
    $.fn.somefunction = function(text, options){
        ...function code goes here
    };

    $('.selector_name').on.somefunction();
})(jQuery);
```

but that gives me a JScript runtime error: "Object doesn't support property or method 'somefunction'.

How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind your function to dynamically loaded elements then do it when they are added.

```
var $newElem = $('div');
$newElem.somefunction();
```

`on` binds to events, not to functions.

```
$(selector).on('click', function() { ... });
```

There is no 'on element created' method in jQuery. When you are adding them you will need to do the work of binding to them if need be.

---

```
//load some content via ajax
$('div').load('foo.html');
//rebind your function if need be
$('div').children('span').somefunction();
```

Comment: OK - I see my misunderstanding here.  However these elements are being dynamically reloaded via ajax.  I'm not loading the elements in my script.  So I'm still not clear on how to do this.

Comment: @daveywc - If you are receiving html via ajax and appending it to your page then you will need to reattach your function if need be. See my updated answer.

Comment: rebind should be inside the callback function.

Comment: @mrtsherman - reattaching/rebinding my function to the elements in the success method of my ajax call worked:  i.e. simply calling $('.selector_name').somefunction(); in the success method.

Answer (score 2):

on is valid only for events. you can bind it to custom event as well.

```
$('.selector_name').on("somefunction", function(){
   ****
});
```

but you have to trigger it again

```
$('.selector_name').trigger("somefunction");
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

---

[working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/85XpF/2/)

Comment: hope you will read the document in the above link and understand that `on` is associating event(including custom events) to any dynamically added element. so when you call `trigger` it will trigger the event already associated by `on`

Comment: +1 - Okay, got it. Thanks so much for taking the time to post a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [jQuery documentation for .on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

The syntax for using on is:

```
.on( events [, selector] [, data], handler(eventObject) )
```

So as an example, it would like like this:

```
$("#dataTable tbody tr").on("click", function(event){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Or if you want to use a selector, for live events, on will "watch" the selected `tr` (second parameter) for changes:

```
$("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "tr", function(event){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```